# creating a drop down list in javascript from a text file

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

Is this possible? If so, I could really use some help on this. I'm very new to JavaScript and thus hardly know any of the syntactical specifications, nor proper methodology.

**Some functions I wrote in an external file.**

```
var base = base || {};

base.requestAjax = function () {

    try{

        return new XMLHttpRequest();

    } catch (e) {

        try {

            return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

        } catch (e) {

            try {

                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            } catch (e) {

                alert("Something is wrong with your browser! Please ensure that you have javascript functionality enabled");
                return false;
            }
        }
      }
}

base.onReadyStateChange = function(ajaxRequest, formName, formArray, method, controller) {

    var methodVerified = verifyMethod(method);

    if (!methodVerified) {
        throw new Exception("Error: please make sure the method passed matches that of \'GET\' or \'POST\'.");
    } 

    for (input in formArray) {
        document.formName.input.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }

    ajaxRequest.open(method, controller, true);
    file.send(null);
}


base.writeDropDownList = function(file, method, path) {

    var file = upload.requestAjax();

    file.open(method, path, true);

    if (file.readyState != 4) {
        throw new Exception("Error: text file ready state not equal to 4!");
    }

    if (file.status != 200) {
        throw new Exception("Error: text file status not equal to 200!");
    }

    var lines = file.responseText.split("\n");

    document.writeln("<select>");

        for(line in lines) {
        document.writeln("<option>" + line + "</option>");
    }

    document.writeln("</select>");

    file.send(null);    
}

base.verifyMethod = function(method) {

    var methodLower = method.toString().toLowerCase();

    switch(methodLower) {
        case "get":
        case "post":
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

**The html code which attempts to implement it**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/css/adsmanager.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/base.js">
        <!--
        function createCountriesList() {
            var file = base.requestAjax;
            var path = "../includes/_notes/countries.txt";
            base.writeDropDownList(file, "GET", path);
        }
        //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name='adsManager'>
            <button type="text" value="test" onclick="createCountriesList()" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I plan to use the functions for other things, so I figured I'd create a namespace. I found **[this](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/519292-drop-down-list-text-file)** as a reference and based most of my model off of it.

Thanks to all who can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your point of failure? Is your Javascript sending the Ajax request and receiving the response?

Is `lines` getting data in this line of your code?

```
 var lines = file.responseText.split("\n");
```

If you are getting this far, iterate through `lines` and add options like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('id');
select.options.add(new Option(lines[i]));
```

In your `writeDropDownList` method, I made a few changes:
added a method that will be called when your Ajax call has completed. In that method, you should check the response string and add the options to your select box

```
base.writeDropDownList = function(file, method, path) {

    var file = upload.requestAjax();    
    file.open(method, path, true);    
    file.onreadystatechange = requestComplete;
    file.send(null);    
}
  requestComplete()
  {
    if (file.readyState == 4) 
    {
       if(file.readyState == 200)
       {
           var lines = file.responseText.split("\n");
           //foreach loop to populate select
       }
   }                            
 }
```

In your code, you are checking and using `files.responseText` before you have even sent the Ajax request at `files.send(null)`

EDIT:

Some more comments regarding your code:

- In the `createCountriesList` function, you create `file` and assign
  it a value by calling `requestAjax`. You then pass it to
  `writeDropDownList` function, where you assign it a value again by
  calling `requestAjax`. You see that this is redundant? There is no
  need to create `file` in `createCountriesList` and pass it as an
  argument. Create it just once in `writeDropDownList`.
- in `writeDropDownList` you call `upload.requestAjax()`. What is
  `upload`. I don't see you initializing `upload` anywhere. Do you mean
  to call `base.requestAjax()`?
- you have a function `base.OnReadyStateChange` but at no point are you
  telling your AJAX request to call that function when state changes. See the code I posted above. The function I added called
  `requestComplete` does that, and I tell the AJAX request to call it using `file.onreadystatechange = requestComplete;`
- You set `method` to `GET`, yet you are not passing any GET values in your URL
- in `file.open(method, path, true);`, path is supposed to be the URL of the script the AJAX request will call. You have set `path` to `../includes/_notes/countries.txt`. An AJAX request cannot call a `.txt` file since they do not execute.

I just had a look at the source of your code, and it is all sorts of broken. Please do not use it.

What is `countries.txt` ? Are you attempting to populate a dropdown with a list of all countries, or some countries depending on user's input?

If the former, there is no need for Javascript / AJAX. You need to add PHP code in your html to populate the select box.

If the latter, your AJAX request should be sending the user input as a GET variable.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the critique. I literally just began using javascript, so I don't know a thing about it.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

1. Very nice code; it's readable and looks neat.
2. I'd use a different name than `base` as namespace - for my liking, the word is too "common" . Chances are that you're going to define a variable `base` somewhere and it will break.
3. To create HTML from JavaScript, first create a small example in pure HTML to see how it should look like. After that, create a script which produces the same HTML using `document.createElement()`.
4. Look at frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) because they make many boring tasks much more simple.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. I'll be sure to look into that.